# Is it possible to toggle ÜberCharge visual effects?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

Is it possible for me to toggle ÜberCharge visual effects ***on my end only - so that only I can see the first person effects?*** or better yet can I bind a key to toggle it on and off?

**Note: this is for client-side (my end) only.**

Info. on the effects can be found on the [official wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/%C3%9CberCharge#Effects).

Examples:

-Medic perspective

[image]

-Receiver perspective

[image]

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the effects to provide information?  Turning on effects that aren't actually active sounds like something Valve would deliberately disable, due to it's potential for abuse.

Comment: I think you misunderstood I am asking for the **visual screen effects**. I am not asking how to enable the effects of the ÜberCharge I just want to enable the **screen effects** that it uses.

Comment: That's what I'm referring to, as well.  If you looked like you had an ÜberCharge going, the enemy team would behave differently than if you didn't.

Comment: I just want the screen effects to appear on my end. I would look normal to players I just like the visual effects (in first person). In other words it would not show up to other players just on my side - so it would not be hurting/deceiving anyone.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That makes sense.  I'd recommend you add that into your question; it will probably change the answers you garner.

Comment: Added pictures of what I think you mean, for clairty.  If im wrong, edit and remove them :)

Comment: So let me get this straight - you want to be able to turn on/off the screen-surrounding distortion glow manually, regardless of whether you're Übered or not?

Comment: Yes - that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Why do you need it? How does this help you; how does this help people coming to the site? I could understand wanting to toggle ubers on and off (but you can't do that), but toggling a visual glow regardless of Uber seems completely useless to me

Comment: @Retrosaur - I suppose it'd be easier to tell at a glance who (in a group of people) you are currently healing, without having to rely on the username.

Comment: Hmm, interesting viewpoint

Comment: @Retrosaur it is mainly so I can test custom weapons to make sure all the visual effects work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know exactly why you want to do this, but just to attempt to clear this up:

You can use the console command `addcond 5` to Über yourself. You can use the command `removecond 5` to unÜber yourself. These are both cheats commands, so they require `sv_cheats` to be `1` on the server side.

There is no command to enable or disable only the visual effects. As far as I am aware it is impossible to create a client-side mod that allows you to see the effects when not Übered, as this would require hijacking the rendering code that checks to see whether you are Übered, which seems like it would require ridiculous reverse-engineering and probably might trip VAC.

Answer (score 2):

Client-side? Yes. Server-side? No.

When communicating with another person over a server that is not your own, there is no conceivable method of changing the effects for anybody but you, unless said person performs the same steps as you do. However, even altering the effects is considered tampering with the game, which could, and most likely will, result in a VAC ban.

Comment: I just realized that technically this answers the question, which was phrased as a simple "is it possible" yes-or-no format.  However I am fairly certain the real intended question is "how to achieve this on client-side".

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there is no way to turn off the effects in the way you are talking about. I suppose the reasoning is that, that way everyone has a completely fair playing ground, even if it means it makes it slightly easier for you to see. Just something you have to get used to unfortunately.

Comment: If you read the question, the OP only wants a local visual change, not to change the game mechanics or anything anyone else besides himself could possibly detect.

Comment: Yes, but I believe the UberCharge effect is their to intentionally have the VERY slight disorientating effect that it does have. Therefore removing it gives the player an advantage.

Comment: Actually, the OP likes the visual effect and wants to just keep it on (see this [comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107141/is-it-possible-to-toggle-bercharge-visual-effects/107622?noredirect=1#comment143884_107141)).  I don't find the effect disorienting at all and I think it was just intended as an obvious visual cue so the other team knows to hide when they see it.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Sorry, I misread it into thinking the OP wished to turn it off on their end, sorry! :D